# How to show important values on a graph with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I show the specific values of variables on a graph? 
For example:
ggplot(data=df)+
geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=var))

How do I get it to have the actual count on the bar chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question has asked before but I couldn' find a duplicate quickly.

Here is an example how to annotate the columns of a bar chart with the counts:

```
n_row <- 100L
set.seed(123L)
df <- data.frame(var = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n_row, TRUE, 5:1))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df) + aes(x = var) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  stat_count(geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..), vjust = "bottom")
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can write

```
ggplot(data = df) + aes(x = var, label = ..count..) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  geom_text(stat = "count", vjust = "bottom")
```

Some geoms and stats do compute variables which can be accessed using special names like `..count..`. To plot labels, the x and y positions and the text need to be specified. The x position is taken from the date as specified in `aes()`. The y position seems to be taken automatically from the statistical transformation but the text needs to be specified explicitely.

Suggested reading:

- [Statistical transformations](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations) in *R for Data Science*
- [`ggplot2` homepage](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks I managed to get that to work but would you mind explaining that the code actually does? I'm really new to R

Comment: I just learned that recently when I tried to plot labels on an experimental cumulative distribution function. I've updated my answer with some addtional explanations.